# How to change the language of the keyboard

Tags: android

My Android application has multi language support.my problem is  if I select the language(from application) then  app will changed to corresponding language but keyboard is still in system language any idea to change the keyboard language too.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't have a language picker in the app-  use the system language.  If the user wants to change it, they can there.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really that possible.

The keyboard is itself an application. Therefore, you cannot change it directly from your app, nor can you guarantee that your user will have the "Arabic" charset or addon or whatever, for they keyboard app that they employ.

Your only real and reliable solution if you wish to accomplish what you need would be to create your own keyboard input. Otherwise, it will be in the user's hands to change their keyboard to Arabic.